# Dependency Injection в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, зависимости, dependency-injection

Добрый вечер! У меня появился такой вопрос. Как правильно реализовать внедрение зависимости в WPF?

Проблема вот в чем. Скажем у меня есть приложение которое включает в себя несколько окон в каждом из которых нужно привязывать например интерфейс IFoo к классу Foo. Я имогу сделать привязку конкретных типов к интерфейсам для каждого окна по отдельности но проблема в том что разные окна используют одинаковые интерфейсы и если делать привязку для каждого окна по отдельности то получится дублирование кода - дл\я каждого окна будут выполняться одинаковые привязки, и при этом я не смогу изменить привязку только из одного места в программе. Это нужно будет делать для каждого окна по отдельности. Тогда рушится весь Dependency Injection.  А вот как это сделать так чтобы привязка осуществлялась для всего приложения один раз и была известна ото всюду я не знаю.

Comment: Ничего не понял. Итак, у вас есть несколько окон, каждое из которых получает `IFoo` как VM, правильно? Дальше непонятно: то, что `IFoo` реально реализуется классом `Foo` — это везде в приложении? Должен ли быть для случая другой реализации другой UI? Чем отличается отображение `IFoo` в разных окнах?

Может быть, станет понятнее, если вы объясните не в терминах абстрактных `Foo`/`IFoo`, а конкретных классов (не обязательно точно таких, как у вас).

Comment: IFoo это не ViewModel это модель. Скажем IFoo это некий логгер (можно представить что это не IFoo а ILogger) реализация логера может меняться и с помощью DI я хочу это контролировать. Но я хочу чтобы привязка интерфейса к конкретному типу производилась только в одном месте но как это сделать я не понимаю. Например в  MVC я бы сделал это в Global.asax и все контроллеры знали бы о том что IFoo нужно связать с классом MyFoo. А вот как это сделать в WPF чтобы все окна и их ViewModel знали к чему привязан IFoo я не знаю((

Comment: @JuniorTwo: Так, а причём здесь WPF тогда? Глобальную инициализацию можно сделать где угодно. Например, в конструкторе `App` (или в `override App.OnStartup()`).

Comment: ну просто хотелось бы понять как это правильно делается в WPF. Не понимаю например сделать доступными эти привязки для всех окон ведь если сделать это в конструкторе App  то о них будет знать тоьлко сам App а не окна

Comment: @JuniorTwo: Не совсем понимаю: а как ASP.NET MVC (если я правильно понял вас) «сообщает» всем контроллерам об injected dependency? WPF как фреймворк не предоставляет никаких специальных средств для DI; возможно, вам нужен какой-нибудь [DI-фреймворк](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4581791/276994). Или можно написать несложный велосипед.

Comment: @VladD вы не поняли. Я использую один из фреймворков - Unity. Но я не могу понять как и где мне сделать так чтобы все окна "знали" о том, что интерфейсу IFoo соответствует клас Foo. Я не знаю всех подробностей ASP.NET MVC но знаю что когда я пользуюсь DI в MVC то описываю эти привязки в Global.asax и при создании каждого нового контроллера с таким конструктором

    class MyController : Controller 
    { 
        public MyController(IFoo foo)
        {
        }
    }

сама MVC создает контроллер с помощью этого конструктора и передает ему экземпляр IFoo. И непойму как это сделать в WPF

Comment: @JuniorTwo: Хм. А откуда фреймворк MVC знает, как именно создавать ваш контроллер? Он знает о Unity? Или это, наоборот, Unity умеет «объяснить» MVC, что создавать `MyController` надо через него? (Я не знаком ни с MVC, ни с Unity.)

---
Встречный вопрос: а как вы собираетесь в WPF делать так, чтобы фреймворк за вас создавал экземпляры контроллеров? WPF этого не делает.

Comment: @VladD ну вы же понимаете о чем я говорю. Я не эксперт в MVC и не знаю всех подробностей как там происходит создание контролеров и как IoC контейнеры взаимодействуют с контроллерами. Но я хочу узнать как в WPF сделать так что бы интерфейсы можно было инициализировать в одном месте и чтобы об этом знали все окна. 

>Встречный вопрос: а как вы собираетесь в WPF делать так, чтобы фреймворк за вас создавал экземпляры контроллеров?

об этом я и спрашиваю. Как это сделать или как обойти это что бы все окна знали какие классы привязаны  к каким интерфейсам

Comment: @JuniorTwo: нет, не понимаю, честное слово. У меня нету опыта с MVC-фреймворком, и я не знаю, как именно они дружат с Unity.

О WPF я знаю больше, и там контроллеры автоматически **не** создаются, вы должны **сами** вызвать конструктор, и сами передать в него аргумент. Ничего не происходит неявно.

Но если у вас есть DI-контейнер, то внутри любого окна вы сможете получить привязку из этого самого контейнера.

Comment: >О WPF я знаю больше

так вот и объясните пожалуйста если вас не затруднит - КАК ПРАВИЛЬНО СДЕЛАТЬ DI В WPF??? Именно об этом я и прошу у вас в который раз. В каком конкретно месте в приложении делать привязку интерфейсов? Как сделать так чтобы все вьюмодели знали об этой привязке? Как сделать это только один раз для всего приложения??? Как?

Comment: @JuniorTwo: Так всё просто: так же, как и без WPF! При инициализации программы вы инициализируете DI-контейнер (так, как это полагается делать в Unity). Для этого хорошим местом является либо конструктор `App`, либо `App.OnStartup()`. Далее во всех местах, где вы создаёте контроллер (а это вы делаете _вручную_), получаете нужный экземпляр `IFoo` у DI-контейнера.

Comment: @JuniorTwo _"как это сделать так чтобы привязка осуществлялась для всего приложения один раз и была известна ото всюду"_ -- посмотрите ответ [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/480040)

Answer (score 13):

Прежде всего вам надо использовать паттерн [Model-View-ViewModel](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-ViewModel) в своем WPF-приложении, если вы еще не делаете этого.

В приложении, реализованном с применением MVVM, окна содержат только XAML-разметку, а вся логика находится в моделях представлений. Именно в моделях представлений вам придется использовать внедрение конструктора для получения зависимостей. Вот так может выглядеть конструктор модели представления окна, который принимает в качестве зависимости `IFoo`:

```
public class SomeWindowViewModel
{
    public SomeWindowViewModel(IFoo foo)
    {
    }
}
```

Далее. Корневым объектом в вашем графе зависимостей будет модель представления главного окна приложения. Это будет первый объект, который создаст контейнер внедрения зависимоcтей и он должен быть создан раньше чем будет показано главное окно. Модель представления главного окна может принимать в качестве зависимостей `IFoo` и любые другие необходимые объекты:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public MainWindowViewModel(IFoo foo, ISomeService service /*и т.д.*/)
    {
    }
}
```

Корень компоновки, то место где вы единственный раз определите все привязки, и соберете ваш граф объектов, должен находится в точке входа приложения. В случае с WPF-приложением точкой входа является класс `App`, и здесь есть небольшая проблема. По умолчанию файл `App.xaml` выглядит вот так:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Здесь строчка `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"` декларативно указывает фреймворку, что при запуске приложения должно быть создано и отображено окно `MainWindow.xaml`. Чтобы взять контроль в свои руки вы должны удалить строку `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"` и создать окно сами в методе `OnStartup` класса `App`. Теперь вы контролируете процесс создания окна и можете привязать к нему его `ViewModel`. При этом не следует создавать модель представления главного окна самостоятельно. Вместо этого надо получить ее из контейнера внедрения зависимоcтей,  позволив тем самым контейнеру самостоятельно построить граф объектов. На примере **CastleWindsor** это будет выглядеть так:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        // создаем контейнер внедрения зависимостей
        var container = new WindsorContainer()

        // подключаем модуль, в котором прописаны привязки
        // (этот модуль - то самое место, где мы прописываем привязки 
        // единственный раз)
        container.Install(new MainInstaller())

        // теперь, когда контейнер осведомлен о привязках,
        // мы можем запросить у него ViewModel, и контейнер вернет 
        // ее нам, самостоятельно разрешив все зависимости
        var viewModel = container.Resolve<MainWindowViewModel>();

        // теперь можно показывать главное окно
        var mainWindow = new MainWindow();            
        mainWindow.DataContext = viewModel;
        mainWindow.Show();            
    }
}
```

Comment: Полагаю, в классе `MainWindowViewModel` Вы имели в виду конструктор? (сейчас там `AnyWindowViewModel`)

Comment: @soon верно, исправил