# Как в App определить зависимости и как их получить в MainWindow?

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть несколько наследников `Window`, включая `MainWindow`.
В `App` решается какой из `Window` надо открыть. Но перед этим должны быть созданы все зависимости, необходимые в `MainWindow`. Некоторые из зависимостей должны создаваться в `App` при каждом запросе. Например, если в `MainWindow` требуется реализация `IFoo`, то при каждом запросе в `App` надо создавать новый объект.
Как можно определить зависимости в `App` и как их передать в `MainWindow`? И при этом надо использовать только то, что есть в WPF, т.е. без подключения каких-либо сборок с IoC и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

В такой ситуации можно использовать ресурсы `App`.
Например, есть интерфейс `IFoo` и его реализация определяется в `App`. Если надо создавать каждый раз новый объект, то в ресурсы можно поместить `Func<IFoo>`.

Model.cs

```
interface IFoo {
   void Hello();
}

delegate void Log(string str);
```

App.xaml.cs

```
public partial class App : Application {

  class Foo : IFoo {
     public void Hello() { Console.WriteLine("hello"); }
  }

  public App() {
     // объект создается по запросу
     this.Resources.Add(typeof(IFoo), new Func<IFoo>(() => new Foo()));
     // 'ссылка' на метод Trace
     this.Resources.Add(typeof(Log), new Log(Trace));
  }

  void Trace(string str) {
     Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " " + str);
  }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
partial class MainWindow : Window {
  public MainWindow() {
     InitializeComponent();

     var f = this.Get<IFoo>();    // получить реализацию IFoo
     f.Hello();
     var log = this.Get<Log>();   // получить 'ссылку' на метод
     log("test");
  }
}

static class WindowExtensions {
  static public T Get<T>(this Window w) {
     var o = w.FindResource(typeof(T));
     return (o.GetType() == typeof(Func<T>)) 
            ? ((Func<T>)o)() 
            : (T)o;
  }
}
```

Результат

```
hello
1/5/2016 1:54:11 PM test
```