# IntelliSense в XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

Подскажите, какие условия нужно выполнить, что в XAML при бинденге работал IntelliSense, подсвечивая доступные VM поля для биндинга?

Контекст я присваиваю через конструктор своего окна.

Comment: "через конструктор своего окна." в codebehind или в xaml разметке?

Comment: попробуйте контекст присвоить в самой xaml разметке

Comment: @Cruz21 в codebehind. А если у меня там внедрение зависимостей через конструктор?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/349538/dependency-injection-%D0%B2-wpf
и попробуйте сделать, то что выше написал

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [IntelliSense для ViewModel в редакторе XAML Visual Studio](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/678612/intellisense-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-viewmodel-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5-xaml-visual-studio)